# Export to Excel exports the whole webpage and not just the gridview(Sorting enabled)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel, gridview-sorting

In my C# application, I am generating a Gridview from user's input and then I have to give user an option to export the Gridview to the excel sheet.

Here is my abc.aspx page:

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <b>Enter p1 :</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_P1" runat="server" />
            <br />

            <b>Enter p2 :</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_P2" runat="server" /><br />



            <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Start Search" ClientIDMode="Static" />
           <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Export Data to Excel" />
            <hr />

                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"

                        ShowFooter="false"
                       AllowSorting="true"
                        OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
                        EnableViewState="false"
                       ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
                        AllowPaging="false">
                        <RowStyle Wrap="false" />
                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="false" />
                    </asp:GridView>    
        </div>

    </form>
    <br />  
</body>
```

Here my .cs page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;

public partial class pSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet dsldata;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string fname = filename.Text;


        GridView1.DataSource = (DataSet)Session["data"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        int rowCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
        if (rowCount == 0)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Result Empty!');</script>");
        }
        else
        {
                ExportToExcel(GridView1, fname);
        }
    }



    private void ExportToExcel(GridView GrdView, string fname)
    {

        try
        {
            Response.AddHeader("contentdisposition", "attachment;filename=test1.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            GrdView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
        }
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control control)
    {
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Rname= Page.Request.QueryString["rname"];
        string typeofquery = "my command";

        string abc = null;
       abc = "" + typeofquery + " @RName='" + RName "'";

        SqlDataAdapter cmdldata = new SqlDataAdapter(abc, sqlconn);
        cmdldata.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;
        dsldata = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            cmdldata.Fill(dsldata);
            Session["data"] = dsldata;
            GridView1.DataSource = dsldata;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }//end of try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Response.Write(ex);

        }//end of catch

    }

    private const string ASCENDING = " ASC";
    private const string DESCENDING = " DESC";


    public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

            return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
        }
        set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
    }


    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

        if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, ASCENDING);
        }

    }

    private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
    {
        dsldata = (DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Session["data"];
        DataTable dt = dsldata.Tables[0];
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;
        dt = dv.ToTable();
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet("table");
        ds1.Tables.Add(dt);
        Session["data"] = ds1;
        GridView1.DataSource = dv;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

I have sorting enabled in my gridview.
The problem is: my whole web page is getting exported to the excel sheet. I want only my grid view to be exported.The sorting is working properly and I do get new sorted table in my excel sheet but it is with the whole web page.
I have looked for solution on different places on internet.Seems like many people have faced this problem.I have also tried their solutions like 
changing the   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"; to
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; and most of the other solutions were similar to my  ExportToExcel() function.

I have been wokring on this thing since last 2 days but nothing is working for my application.

Please Help!
Thank you in advance!

Changed my ExporttoExcel function

```
private void ExportToExcel(GridView GrdView, string fname)
{

try
{

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fname + ".xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
}
}
```

Comment: I just realised that when I remove OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" and AllowSorting="true" in the gridview in abc.aspx page I get the excel sheet with only gridview.Only when I have these two enabled,the problem is arising.Please help
!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem.I realized that the problem was in AllowSorting feature of my gridview.I turned off the eventvalidation of that page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="abc.aspx.cs" Inherits="abc" EnableEventValidation = "false" %>
```

This worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `Response.Clear()` at the top of your `Export ToExcel()` function.

Comment: I have edited my ExportToExcel (have edited my question) function stil things are not working.What should I do?